# Write a program that corrects an extra character in a string

Tags: c++

> Write a C++ program that corrects an extra character in a string.
>
> For example:
>
> Input
>
> ```
> Excellent time too listen to music
> ```
>
> Output
>
> ```
> Excellent time to listen to music
> ```

I am new to C++ and do not understand how to do this. Can somebody please help?

Comment: Do you understand what you are supposed to do, but don't understand how to do to it in C++? I know C++ but I don't understand what you are supposed to be doing, could you explain it a little more clearly? Perhaps give some more examples of the corrections you are expected to make.

Comment: The first part of programming is to a large extent language-agnostic. Before writing code, you have to know what you want the code to do, step-by-step. What are the steps you want the computer to perform? (If you do not know how to implement one of these steps, try breaking that step down into smaller steps.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ you can use the string library to perform string manipulation. Here I have used 2 methods of the string library to answer your question

**Method 1** : Using `replace()`

```
string sentence = "Excellent time too listen to music";
sentence.replace(15, 3 , "to"); // replaces string found in 15th position, 3 places, with the string to 
cout << "Using str.replace method : " << sentence << endl;
```

**Method 2** : Using `erase()`

```
string sentence = "Excellent time too listen to music";
sentence.erase(17,1); // erases the 17th character, and erase 1
cout << "Using str.erase method : " << sentence << endl;
```

Comment: The string `"Excellent time too listen to music"` is just example input. How do you make this work for the general case of correcting "an extra character in a string"? (Since there is no specification of what makes a character "extra", I'm inclined to think there should not be an answer until the question has been clarified.)

Comment: I agree with @JaMiT.If there is no specification as to what makes a character extra, then a general solution can't be derived. But the answer given was based on the desired output. So it is assumed that "too" had an extra "o" according to the question.

Comment: If a full solution can't be given, then the question might fall into the category of questions that should not be answered. See [answer], where it goes over "Not all questions can or should be answered here."